# Disable services from context menu by Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, contextmenu

I know I can disable the context menu items by going to **System preferences > Keyboard > Shortcut** but I want to disable services by commandline.

Does anyone knows if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that you can add your services to the file in `~/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist`

Aftwards you call:

- `> launchctl stop com.apple.pbs`
- `> launchctl start com.apple.pbs`